# Why jQuery token based integration in Angular does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to integrate jQuery as a service in an Angular 6 application and I followed the article: https://thecodegarden.net/jquery-in-angular-typescript-without-type-definition/#comment-2311

The only difference is that my solution use `InjectionToken` instead of `OpaqueToken` which has been deprecated since Angular 4.

Ok, now about the code itself.

The jQuery service where the issue where the root cause seems to occur, the `jqueryFactory` returns `undefined`:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQUERY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');

export function jqueryFactory() {
  // return undefined...
  return  window['jQuery'];
}

export const JQUERY_SERVICE = { provide: JQUERY_TOKEN, useFactory: jqueryFactory };
```

The AppModule: `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { JQUERY_SERVICE } from './jquery.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ JQUERY_SERVICE ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The AppComponent: `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Inject, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JQUERY_TOKEN } from './jquery.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  constructor(@Inject(JQUERY_TOKEN) private $: any) { }

  public paragraphCount = 0;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paragraphCount = this.$('p').length;
  }
}
```

and its related template: `app.component.html`

```
<h1>HelloW!</h1>
<p>
  Seems there is {{ paragraphCount }} paragraph in this component template.
</p>
```

And last but not the least the `angular.json`:

```
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ]
```

An example of this application is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2plus-jquery-token-based-eaxnzs

[EDIT]

Seems the underlying issue is more about StackBlitz as pointed by user184994 github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/407

A working example is available on codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/3vmzyrj4w1

Comment: Part of the problem is that the factory may be created before the page has fully loaded, i.e. before `window['jQuery']` exists. Is there any reason for you wanted to use it in a service?

Comment: @user184994 I thought that when it comes to unit testing the dependency could then be mocked whenever it is needed.

Comment: That makes sense. You could always change the service so that it has a function. which in turn returns `window['jQuery']`? That way, it will only try to read it from `window` when you're ready

Comment: @user184994 this is exactly what I was thinking about

Comment: @user184994 seems jQuery is not even properly imported... =/ nothing in the windows object even after loading everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** **EDIT** **

I've found that by moving the `script` tag for the CDN link into the `head` tag, the rest of your code will work. See [this example](https://angular2plus-jquery-token-based-rgots2.stackblitz.io/) for more

** **Original Answer** **

Part of the problem is that the factory may be created before the page has fully loaded, i.e. before `window['jQuery']` exists.

What you could do to get around this, is to use `useValue` instead of `useFactory`, and have your service act as a factory. What I mean is this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQUERY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');

export function jqueryFactory() {
  return getJquery();
}

function getJquery() {
  return window['jQuery'];
}

export const JQUERY_SERVICE = { provide: JQUERY_TOKEN, useValue: jqueryFactory };
```

And then in your component, you can initialise `$`, like so:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(@Inject(JQUERY_TOKEN) private $factory: any) { }

  public paragraphCount = 0;
  public $: any;


  public ngOnInit() {
    this.$ = this.$factory();
    this.paragraphCount = this.$('p').length;
  }

}
```

[Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2plus-jquery-token-based-wuxptx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

A couple of things to point out:

- I don't think Stackblitz will look at your Angular.json file, so I've just added a link to the jquery CDN into `index.html`. Outside of Stackblitz, you shouldn't need to do this
- I've changed the lifecycle function to `ngOnInit` instead, otherwise you'll see issues about the value changing after change detection has already run

Comment: I am going to submit an issue ticket on github to Stackblitz.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret It looks like they're already aware https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/407

Comment: @ user184994 true =/ checking out codesandbox and see whether it supports it.

Comment: seems to work out with codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/3vmzyrj4w1
Thanks for your help!